# Alternative to jQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am currently using the jQuery Mobile List View with dividers for a contact list in my PhoneGap app. But I have found it to be very flaky with large number of items in the list. The two main issues I have found are

1. Scrolling a long list doesn't work well. Need to integrate with iScroll.
2. The iScroll integration often causes errors when a scroll will register as a click.

Is there a simple stand alone list view I can replace it with? I don't want to totally replace jQueryMobile at this stage.

Comment: What is the size of your list? JQM has issues with scroll as well as click for large lists.

Comment: Several hundred items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider displaying it in a table and using classes from the jQuery Mobile CSS to quickly style it. Or you could remove the default application of listview and just style it yourself.

It may be worth taking a step back and, from a user's point of view, considering whether such a long list is friendly for the end-user (let alone jQuery mobile).

Comment: It is a contacts list and there are similarly long lists in contacts app on iPhone which is fairly user friendly (except the jQuery Mobile one is very clunky).

Comment: I ended up just creating my own list and styling it as you suggest. jQuery Mobile is not really up to the task.